# Carregando arquivos RData do próprio diretório do arquivo .R

Tags: r

Como fazer pra carregar arquivos RData que estão no mesmo diretório do arquivo .R, no RStudio?

Aqui, por exemplo, há a linha:

`load('teste.RData')`

Quando carregada, ela retorna...

```
Erro em readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) : 
  não é possível abrir a conexão
Além disso: Mensagens de aviso perdidas:
In readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE) :
  não foi possível abrir o arquivo comprimido 'teste.RData', motivo provável 'Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado'
```

Isso não ocorre quando eu dou o caminho da pasta: 

`load('~/Downloads/teste.RData')`

Por que isso ocorre? É normal? Como fazer para carregar sem dar todo  o caminho?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O R procura o arquivo no diretório padrão dele. Para mudar o diretório padrão, veja

```
?setwd.
```

No seu caso, tente:

```
setwd('/Downloads/')
```

ou

```
setwd('~/Downloads/')
```

Atualização da minha resposta, após os comentários:

1. Abra algum editor de texto como o notepad++ e salve como .Rprofile o conteúdo abaixo (não esquecer do "." no nome do arquivo).

   ```
   .First <- function(){
     cat("\nWelcome to R!\n",sep="")
     cat("---------------\n\n",sep="")
     if(file.exists("~/novodiretorio.r")){
       source("~/novodiretorio.r")
       cat("novodiretorio.r foi carregado, mudando o diretório padrão do R")
     }
   }
   ```
2. Abra algum editor de texto como o notepad++ ou mesmo o editor de script do R e salve como .R o conteúdo abaixo

   ```
   setwd("caminho") ## coloque o caminho onde está seu arquivo
   ```
3. Abra o Rstudio e no console digitem getwd() para obter o diretório padrão do R
4. Em posse do diretório, salvem nele os dois arquivos acima.
5. Agora é só abrir e fechar o Rstudio.

ps.: Veja se tudo funciona. Não testei aqui, mas deve funcionar se tudo for feito direito. Veja particularmente se o Rprofile está com o "ponto" na frente. Já tive problemas com isso.

Comment: Não há como colocar direto no path?
Baixei um  zip de um amigo meu e coloquei um arquivo RData e um R no mesmo diretório. No R, já havia o `load("arquivo.RData")`. Mesmo nesse caso, eu preciso setar o diretório de trabalho?

Comment: Não sei se entendi sua pergunta. Você pode alterar o arquivo .RProfile, para ele mudar o diretório padrão na inicialização. É isso que você quer, que o R mude o diretório default sempre que iniciar? Se for, eu edito minha resposta para explicar como faz isso.

Comment: O R file está carregado no RStudio. Eu quero saber como  carregar o RData que está no mesmo diretório do arquivo R, sem ter de me referir diretamente a qual diretório é na linha `load`.

Comment: uma alternativa à alteração do .RProfile é fazer uso do R Project do RStudio. Uma das coisas que ele faz é definir a pasta associada ao projeto como o diretório padrão, além de outras vantagens.

Comment: Muito bom, @Athos